# Ubuntu Version for Intel Core Duo

Tags: system-installation, macosx

I ran:

```
sudo-do-release-upgrade
```

Next, I choose the kernel I want in GRUB2, and then it loads the Ubuntu GUI. Herein, I get the error, "system program detected" and it freezes. Therefore, the mouse doesn't move nor is the keyboard responsive. All that is left to do is hard shutdown.

Specs below:

Mac OS X (bought in 2006, which previously had Tiger yet upgraded to 10.6.8) with an Intel Core Duo 1.83 GHz

```
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

I typed:

```
lsblk
```

and got:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1      409639      204819+  ee  GPT
/dev/sda2   *      409640   213618175   106604268   af  HFS / HFS+
/dev/sda3       213618688   213620735        1024   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       213620736   304187391    45283328   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 2004 MB, 2004877312 bytes
76 heads, 11 sectors/track, 4683 cylinders, total 3915776 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18
```

Question: should I do a clean install of 13.10? Or is there another Ubuntu version that works well with Processor I mentioned above? The thing is even when I had 12.04 (32 bit), the updates would never run completely. I also had issues with using shutdown, reboot, and suspend. I did a lot of GRUB2 editing yet no luck.

Comment: I doubt the freezes (and other problems) have anything to do with the CPU model. Anyway, there is no special Ubuntu just for CoreDuos.

Comment: @ricomon What  do you mean by "When I get into Ubuntu"? Does it freeze during the boot process? Does it freeze after login? Does it freeze once you turn the computer on?

Comment: Which Intel Core Duo 1.83 GHz? T2400 32 bits. T5550 64 bits. T5600 64 bits. ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: @Grammargeek, I choose the kernel I want in GRUB2, and then it loads the Ubuntu GUI.  Herein, I get the error, "system program detected" and it freezes.  Therefore, the mouse doesn't move nor is the keyboard responsive.  All that is left to do is hard shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

If your Intel Core Duo 1.83 GHz is a T2400, try this:

## Refind:

Is a boot manager that will allow you to choose between Mac OS X, Gnu/Linux, and other operating systems when you boot your computer.

Installing rEFInd makes the dual-boot process easier.

Go to the rEFInd page on SourceForge to download the latest refind-bin-0.8.7.zip file:

[Download site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/files/0.8.7/refind-bin-0.8.7.zip/download)

Open a Terminal window by pressing `Command + Space` and, typing `Terminal`, and pressing `Enter`.

`Drag and drop` the `install.sh` file from the downloaded zip file into the `terminal window` and press `Enter` to run it.

After it was installed successfully.

Shut down your Mac — a `full shut down`, not a restart.

You should see the `rEFInd boot manager screen`.

You’ll need to download an Ubuntu ISO file:`ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-i386.iso`

[Download site](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-i386.iso)

Burn the ISO to `disc` or follow Ubuntu’s official instructions to create a bootable `USB drive` from the ISO file.

[Instructions Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)

`Restart` your computer and `rEFInd` will appear.

Select the `USB` or `disc drive` containing the Ubuntu system and `boot it` on your Mac.

`Launch` the `Install` Ubuntu application from the desktop and install Ubuntu as you normally would.

Be sure to select the `Install Ubuntu alongside Mac OS X` option instead of overwriting your Mac OS X system with Ubuntu.

The installation process should otherwise be normal.

Whenever you `boot` your computer, you’ll have the ability to `choose` between `Mac OS X` and `Ubuntu` on the `rEFInd boot manager screen`.

Comment: I already have REFIT